# Do campaign modifiers affect your score in Batman: Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

Do the campaign modifiers, such as regenerating health or invincible enemies, affect your score? It seems strange to include modifiers in the canned campaigns if they don't. I get why they would exist in a sandbox environment, but not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't, no. The trick is that you have to use every modifier by the end of the campaign; part of scoring 9/9 on the campaigns is knowing when to use what modifier where.

I imagine they exist because the campaigns are made up of the individual scenarios, and stringing three together doesn't really make the campaign feel much different.

Comment: Got it. I didn't realize you had to use them all by the end. Makes sense now. I just assumed they were completely optional (but apparently have always used them all considering I've finished a few campaigns.)

Comment: I see what you mean. It's easy to miss the forced modifier selection in the third round.